# は or が to describe something with an adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives, は-and-が

I know that は is used for general purposes when describing something with an adjective, and が is more suited for specific things, but in the examples below which sentence is correct?

> 先生の言ったこと**は**大体正しいからきちんと聞かないとだめです。

> 先生の言ったこと**が**大体正しいからきちんと聞かないとだめです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, but they mean different things.

先生の言ったこと**は**大体正しい is a description of a general fact, "What your teachers say (every day) is correct most of the time". On the other hand, 先生の言ったこと**が**大体正しい means "What the teacher (just) said is correct for the most part". This is used when the teacher's specific opinion and someone else's opinion are at odds right now.

Comment: I often recommend that people think of が as often meaning "X is the thing which is ...", so the sentence with が it's saying "what the teacher said is the correct thing (out of the available options)"